# How can I customise the dictation view in presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, textinput, dictation

I made a page with a presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions and I want to customise the dictation view.

I don't want to see "Cancel" but "Retry" for example.

I saw that in Messages app, the dictation view is the default view but with "Send" and not "Done".

Do you have an idea if this customisation is available and how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to customize the Cancel and Done buttons.

Apple can use their private API methods to customize the UI/UX for their apps to do what we can't (yet).

Best thing to do is to [submit a feature request](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

*You can determine what you're able to change by looking at the documentation methods or examining the header files, both of which are readily available within Xcode.*